# Plone: custom variable in content rule

Tags: plone, plone-4.x

I have defined a dexterity content type myaddon.subscriber (subscriber = participant at an event).

I added a Content rule to send an email when a subscriber is approved (workflow state change to this one).

Each subscriber has an email address (email - field).

In Edit Mail Action form I see I can use variables like `${user_email}` in `Email recipients (Required)
The email where you want to send this message. To send it to different email addresses, just separate them with ,`

This is working. In my case `user_email` is the email of logged in user - the person who approve the participant. The messages are sent when the state is changed. Perfect.

I need to define a variable `${subscriber_email}` that will have the myaddon.subscriber.email value. How can I do this? I'm trying to find an example. So, how to use an field (email) of current changed object (subscriber) as variable in this Mail Action?

Comment: You may have better luck posting questions on our forum, https://community.plone.org (more eyeballs), though I will post a link on the forum to your question here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `IContextWrapper` from **plone.stringinterp 1.0.14+**:

```
>>> new_context = IContextWrapper(context)(
...     email=u"subscriber@example.com"
... )

>>> class SubscriberEmailSubstitution(BaseSubstitution):
...     def safe_call(self):
...         return self.wrapper.email

>>> sm = getGlobalSiteManager()
>>> sm.registerAdapter(SubscriberEmailSubstitution, (Interface, ), IStringSubstitution, name=u"subscriber_email")

>>> getAdapter(new_context, IStringSubstitution, 'subscriber_email')()
u'subscriber@example.com'
```

Imports:

```
>>> from zope.interface import Interface
>>> from plone.stringinterp.interfaces import IStringSubstitution
>>> from plone.stringinterp.interfaces import IStringSubstitutionInfo
>>> from zope.component import getGlobalSiteManager, getAdapter
>>> from plone.stringinterp.adapters import BaseSubstitution
>>> from plone.stringinterp.interfaces import IContextWrapper
```

See more stringinterp [doctests](https://github.com/plone/plone.stringinterp/blob/master/plone/stringinterp/tests/wrapperTests.txt#L67).

Also see a fully working example within [eea.pdf](https://github.com/collective/eea.pdf/blob/master/eea/pdf/browser/app/download.py#L148) add-on.